# Alternatives to the noun 'dump' (as in "a data dump")

Tags: synonyms

What are alternatives to the noun 'dump' (as in "a data dump")?

The word *dump* here refers to the data that gets dumped, in other words, to the mass of what is being dumped. Another not-so-common example might be "She gave me a feelings dump," meaning, "She dumped all her feelings on me" (perhaps in an emotional outburst), or, "The professor gave me a rules dump" referring to when he gave me a stern lecture about the rules after I arrived late to class.

(This is a somewhat non-standard use of the word 'dump' so the thesaurus is letting me down.)

Comment: Perhaps the word _sink_ could be used, but I've always thought the "dump" in "data dump" functioned more as a verb than a noun.

Comment: I'm definitely familiar of it as a noun, and in this usage it has a different sense than the one you're thinking of with 'sink'. 'Sink' to me suggests a destination. 'Dump' here refers to the (big, unsorted) mass of data itself.

Comment: That clarification helps; armed with that, the best I can think of off the top of my head is _raw data_, but I don't think that's an ideal fit, either.

Comment: Repository, storage? Or as you stated yourself - data mass, it all depends on how you intend on using it.

Comment: Why do you want a substitute? *Dump* is perfect. We also use it in constructions like *core dump*, where it implies disclosure of pretty much everything. It's a great word.

Comment: I rarely downvote a request for a word for a particular meaning, but have done so for this question because of my disappointment with its lack of context and motivation.  Edit question to explain where you'll use the word, mention words that nearly work, and I'll reverse vote.  Also say if any words like image, copy, snap or snapshot, readout, inchoate mass are relevant.

Comment: I have to agree. There are several words (mentioned in these comments and the answers so far) that can be used instead of dump in some cases, but none of them are precise (and *sink* is just wrong - that's where something goes, not what goes there). There might be an answer that worked for a very particular case, but otherwise *dump* seems to be the one to go for. Contrary to some claims, we don't use jargon for the sake of being obscure, but because they allow for very clear meanings.

Comment: @JonHanna: For the record, I agree that _sink_ is wrong; but I suggested that word before further clarification was given.  (My suggesting _sink_ helped the O.P. give additional information that wasn't discernable from the original question.)

Comment: "'dump' (as in "a data dump")" is "too localized".

Comment: One of my colleagues attached several dump files in his email and wrote "I took several dumps for you" :D

Comment: Thanks for the edit J.R., it captured what I was after. I accept the criticism!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see no reason to seek another word. Although this use of *dump* may be ‘non-standard’ in ordinary discourse, it appears to be ‘standard’ within the field in which your discourse will presumably take place. The fact that you cannot readily come up with a ‘better’ term suggests that ‘dump’ is in fact the *best* term.

Most of your audience will understand the term, and may be confused if you use a different one  (“Hmm ... is  he talking about something *other* than an ordinary data dump?”) If you are concerned that some of your audience may be novices or outsiders who will not understand the term, then it is courteous to provide a definition in a footnote or in parentheses; but the term should not be avoided. Those users are presumably seeking to learn about the field, and it is a disservice to them to use a non-standard term which they will not encounter in further reading.

Comment: +1 I agree that it is best to use standard terminology and provide an explanation for people who may not be familiar with it.

Comment: You're probably right, so I'll accept this. The reason I was looking for another word was to use in a context like 'a feelings dump' - I wondered whether there were words with better connotations.

Comment: @tog22 I misunderstood; I thought you were looking for a technical term that would *lack* the emotional context! --Do you want a less slangy term such as "outpouring", or merely a colloquial alternative like "unloaded on me"? Don't Accept until you've got the right word.

Comment: I just want any alternatives there are, suitable for different context - including ones for contexts where you want a less charged word than 'outpouring' or 'dump'. I'll unaccept and see if anyone can come up with any, and otherwise reaccept!

Comment: No one did so accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

The only other choice I can think of that fits in the place of *dump* is *extract*:

> Here is a massive data extract from Globotech's ERP system.  You'd think 20G would be a full extract, but this is actually just their bug description table.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest the following words, each appropriate depending on the context:

[***cache***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cache?s=t)

[***depot***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/depot?s=t)

[***repository***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/repository?o=100074)

[***emporium***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/emporium?s=t)

[***warehouse***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/warehouse?s=t)

[***entrepot***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/entrepot?s=t)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that it depends on context. But you can consider the following:

- data export / exported data
- data assets
- data bank
- source data

There are also other options such as *stash* and *repository* (as suggested in the comments) which are related but unlikely to be what you are looking for.